# Wrap a function and wrap it to a closure by passing modulename into a function

Tags: elixir

Hi I want to make my function more modular and eventually wrap it into a closure.

I currently have this function:

```
  def get_all_perfume_by_name_con_sex(query, name, concentration, gender) do 
    from p in query,
      join: j in Fumigate.Fragrance.PerfumeCompanyJoin, where: p.id == j.perfume_id,
      where: [perfume_name: ^name, 
              concentration: ^concentration,
              gender: ^gender
      ],
      select: j.company_id 
  end
```

I was curious how to pass a module into a function as a parameter more specifically the Fumigate.Fragrance.PerfumeCompanyJoin line.

Is this possible?

```
  def get_all_perfume_by_name_con_sex_modulename(query, name, concentration, gender, modulename) do 
    from p in query,
      join: j in modulename, where: p.id == j.perfume_id,
      where: [perfume_name: ^name, 
              concentration: ^concentration,
              gender: ^gender
      ],
      select: j.company_id 
  end
```

Is something like that possible?

I want to eventually wrap the new function into a closure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works the same way as injecting any other value into a query -- using `^`.

In the query, do this:

```
join: j in ^modulename, where: p.id == j.perfume_id
```

and pass `Fumigate.Fragrance.PerfumeCompanyJoin` to the function call:

```
get_all_perfume_by_name_con_sex_modulename(_, _, _, _, Fumigate.Fragrance.PerfumeCompanyJoin)
```